# Optimizing doctrine queries in Sonata Admin with LeftJoin

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

How do you optimize the DB queries made by sonata admin in the list and edit views ?

i LeftJoined some queries that i made using the querybuilder in my entity repository , this already helped a lot, brought my queries down from 100+ to about 22.

But the remaining queries are the ones that happen automatically by using the formbuilder and listmapper.

Is there anyway i can further optimize the queries made by those classes ?
im not even sure at this point where the queries are made... i tried to overwrite the findBy, findAll methods of the repository but they seem to use something like

```
$persister = $this->_em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityPersister($this->_entityName);
return $persister->load($criteria, null, null, array(), 0, 1, $orderBy);
```

Not sure how i can add a join statement to that...

And i guess it's not just in the sonata admin but also for queries that i use in the front-end that use the built-in EntityRepository find, findAll, findOneBy etc... functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your admin class override the `createQuery()` method like this :

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);

    $query
        ->addSelect(...)
        ->leftJoin(...) // use $query->getRootAlias() here
    ;

    return $query;
}
```

For the edit view it's a little bit more tricky because you need to override the sonata controller by extending `Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController` and then override the `editAction()` method.

The controller name can be specified in the third argument of the service declaration.

Answer (score -1):

I know it some month but if it can help someone :

I didn't wanted to change the controller so i take a look inside the code.

In your admin class, you can override the function getObject($id):

```
// code from sonata admin class
public function getObject($id)
{
    $object = $this->getModelManager()->find($this->getClass(), $id);
    foreach ($this->getExtensions() as $extension) {
        $extension->alterObject($this, $object);
    }
    return $object;
}
```

Then put your own code in and return your object.

That's all, no need to override sonata controller.