# Eager fetching with Sonata list view

Tags: doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I'm using `SonataAdmin` and `SonataDoctrineORMAdmin` bundles to manage entities.

The problem is I can't figure out how to eager fetch the related entities in the list view and as the number of listed entities increase the number of queries executed increasing rapidly as well.

I tried adding `fetch="EAGER" to the relation annotations but the profiles show that Sonata executes the separate queries anyway.

Here's one relation worth of code:

- Post

  ```
  <?php
  namespace Acme\AppBundle\Entity;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

  /**
   * @ORM\Table()
   * @ORM\Entity
   */
  class Post
  {
      /**
       * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
       * @ORM\Id
       * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
       */
      private $id;

      /**
       * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
       **/
      private $name;

      /**
       * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Tag", fetch="EAGER")
       * @ORM\JoinTable(name="join_post_to_tag",
       *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
       *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id",     referencedColumnName="id")}
       *      )
       **/
      private $tags;

      public function getId()
      {
          return $this->id;
      }

      public function setName($names)
      {
          $this->name = $name;
          return $this;
      }

      public function getName()
      {
          return $this->name;
      }

      public function setTags($tags)
      {
          $this->tags = $tags;

          return $this;
      }

      public function __toString()
      {
          return $this->getName();
      }
  }
  ```
- Tag

  ```
  <?php
  namespace Acme\AppBundle\Entity;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

  /**
   * @ORM\Table()
   * @ORM\Entity
   */
  class Tag
  {
      /**
       * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
       * @ORM\Id
       * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
       */
      private $id;

      /**
       * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string", length=255)
       */
      private $value;

      public function getId()
      {
          return $this->id;
      }

      public function setValue($value)
      {
          $this->value = $value;
          return $this;
      }

      public function getValue()
      {
          return $this->value;
      }

      public function __toString()
      {
          return ($this->getValue()) ? : '';
      }
  }
  ```

The first related query that is run is fetching all the posts:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p0_.id AS id0, p0_.id AS id1 
FROM Post p0_ 
  LEFT JOIN join_post_to_tag j1_ ON p0_.id = j1_.post_id 
  LEFT JOIN Tag p1_ ON p1_.id = j1_.target_id 
ORDER BY p0_.id ASC
```

But this does not fetch the related tags or even if it does, it still queries it again:

```
SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.value AS value2 
FROM Tag t0 
  INNER JOIN join_post_to_tag ON t0.id = join_post_to_tag.tag_id 
WHERE join_post_to_tag.post_id = ?
```

I tried to mess with the `createQuery` method in the admin class but could not really find a way to make the related entities fetched correctly.

Is there a way to force the list view to eager fetch the required related entities?

Comment: Have you tried my solution? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, using the createQuery($context) method.
I have achieved eager loading as following:

```php
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
    {
        $query = parent::createQuery($context); // let sonata build it's default query for the entity

        $rootEntityAlias = $query->getRootAlias(); // get the alias defined by sonata for the root entity

        $query->join($rootEntityAlias.'.relationFieldName', 'relationFieldAlias'); // manualy define the join you need
        $query->addSelect('relationFieldAlias'); // this is the key line. It is not enough to join a table. You have to also add it to the select list of the query, so that it's actualy fetched

        // $query->join(...) // repeat the process of joining and selecting for each relation field you need
        // $query->addSelect(...)

        return $query; // return the altered query to sonata. this will only work for the "list" action.
    }
```

If you're having trouble using this, let me know:)

Further reads on this topic: 
[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26447306)

[docs](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html#customizing-the-query-used-to-generate-the-list)